# My JavaScript code won’t work, help please

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a file search program that whatever you type in the textarea it will href a link underneath then you click it. But it ain’t working.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
document.body.innerHTML = '<textarea><\/textarea>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<a href="/Storage/'+ textarea +'>Search<\/a>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you requested. You should separate your logic and assign IDs to your elements to use them efficiently. Once the element is created, you can watch changes on it and use your functions accordingly.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<textarea id="textareaToTrack"><\/textarea>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<a id="linkToModify" href="#">Search<\/a>';
const textareaToTrack = document.getElementById("textareaToTrack");
textareaToTrack.oninput = function modifyLink(e) {
        const textareaValue = textareaToTrack.value;
    document.getElementById("linkToModify").setAttribute("href", "/Storage/" + textareaValue);
};
```